# Cannot read properties using regular method in controller, but works with arrow function

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

I am experiencing an issue where I am unable to use regular class methods to get access to userService.

I want to be able to write regular class methods in my user controller like this:

```
 public async register(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> {
        try {
            const registerDTO: RegisterDTO = req.body;
            const user = await this.userService.register(registerDTO);
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'user created successfully.' });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
```

However when I change the above code to this:

```
 public register = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void>  => {
        try {
            const registerDTO: RegisterDTO = req.body;
            const user = await this.userService.register(registerDTO);
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'user created successfully.' });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
```

It works and data is being properly passed to the service. When I use arrow function instead of regular method it works just as I expect it to, but I prefer to use regular methods.

Then I have user routes like this where data is being passed to the controller:

```
 this.router.post('register', this.userController.register);
```

My user routes are injected with the controller and the controller gets the data, however it stops at the user controller and data doesn't get passed to userService and results in `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')`

I am expecting to be able to use regular methods instead of arrow functions. The error message `Cannot read properties of 'userService'` completely disappears when I change it to an arrow function, but is there a way to keep the regular function and not have to change it? I think that this has something to do with `this.` keyword? I am using inversify dependency injection and the service is being properly injected.

I also know that I can bind it, but I don't think that that is the correct solution. Do I also really have to change the regular methods to arrow functions or is there an approach which does not require such change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption regarding `this` keyword is right: inside a regular function, the value of `this` (the execution context) is dynamic and depends on how the function is invoked. However, inside an arrow function the value of `this` is always resolved lexically and not redefine throughout the lifecycle of the function.

So inside register function, the value of `this` is different when using an  arrow function and when using regular function:

```
const user = await this.userService.register(registerDTO);
```

You can defined your own explicit binding using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or apply, not sure it make your code more readable:

```
this.router.post('register', (req, res, next) => this.userController.register.call(this.userController, req, res, next));
```